# In React, how to add a URL "string" as an object's property, from a Link or other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts, amcharts4

In React, I'm setting an object's URL property (specifically, amcharts chart bullet.url), which is a string, to "../members/{member.name}" It renders with no issues. Clicking the link navigates to the page correctly. However, it seems all the previously loaded states need to be reloaded. Is it a new React "session?"

I've tried setting the property using various expressions using Link. But none seem to compile as expected. Most articles I've found relate to basic usage of Link or persisting state.

The following works rendering and navigating, but all state is gone on new page:

```
let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
let bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
bullet.url = "../Members/{member.name}";
```

I'm thinking there's a React concept I'm missing or an easy way to set a link's URL. I'd like to navigate without "resetting" all the previously loaded states.

Comment: The state of a component is always a Javascript object, and is stored in the main memory. Each components state is mutating until the page refreshes or closes. After that, the page will be initialized with its initial state.

Comment: Based on your error message, you are passing an object value that is a function. You should have posted that error message with your initial post. The value for a url needs to be a string. Convert it if it has integers, `Object.toString();`. You need to access a object value correctly, not a object function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `url`s, use a click (`"hit"`) event to stay within the React ecosystem. If you allow the chart component to be rendered via React Router and export it with `withRouter`, you can take advantage of `this.props.history` on the component itself. As for how to handle the member's name, presuming the `bullet` is actually the template for other bullets, I personally believe the member's name should be part of the chart's data. E.g.

Main component:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

// ...

// main component's render
  <Router>
    <React.Fragment>
      <Route
        path="/"
        render={props => <App {...props} />}
      />
      <Route
        path="/Member/:name"
        render={props => <Person {...props} extra="via router" />}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  </Router>
```

Component that has your chart (e.g. App):

```js
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";

// App's componentDidMount() ...

// ...chart code...

// Member names found in bullet data
chart.data = [ { name: "...", /* ... */ }, /* ... */ ];

// Since we're not using `url`, manually change the cursor to a pointer on hover
bullet.cursorOverStyle = am4core.MouseCursorStyle.pointer;

// Bullet click event
bullet.events.on("hit", event => {
    this.props.history.push('../Members/' + event.target.dataItem.dataContext.name);
});

// ... end App

export default withRouter(App);
```

Here's a fork of our [Column charts with images at top demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-chart-images-top/) in React that when clicking the bullet/images, both updates the main component's state as well as goes to a new URL, and both load the person's info:

https://codesandbox.io/s/olpzok2rxz

If the `member.name` is not part of the chart data and cannot be, it would help to have a sample of your app whether on JSFiddle or CodeSandbox so we can help further.

Comment: Thanks! The bullet hit event and history push worked for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

> In response to my comment.

The state of a component is always a Javascript object, and is stored in the main memory. Each components state is mutating until the page refreshes or closes. After that, the page will be initialized with its initial state.

You could use localStorage or cookies for functionality or a mixin.

> Example

```
const Example = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('counter') || '{}');
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        let self = this;
        setInterval(function () {
            this.setState({
                ticks: this.state.ticks + 1 // Increment
            });
            localStorage.setItem('counter', JSON.stringify(this.state)); // Store
        }, 1000); // Interval
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <span>{this.state.ticks}</span>
    );
    }
});
```

> Link Variable

```
// "../Members/{member.name}";
// Make sure member.name is not an object, but a string
<a href={ `#/..Members/${members.name}` }>{members.name}</a>
```

> Why do you have an error?

***Type.js:171 Uncaught Error: Expected a string or number but got [object Function]***

This is because you are accessing an object value that is a function. You need a string. If it is not a string convert `it Object.toString();`.

```js
// You are not accessing the object correctly
const param = {
  id: function() {
     // This is what it's seeing
  },
  // Needs to be
  id: '../members/id'
}

console.log(param.id);
```

Comment: Thanks @raymond, I can persist the state, just seems like there should be a way to script the setting of a URL.

Comment: `<Redirect to='/target' /> or <Link to="/netflix">` through `import { Redirect, Link } from "react-router-dom"`

Comment: Tried those too, however each of those types of implementation lead to an error:
`Type.js:171 Uncaught Error: Expected a string or number but got [object Function]`

Comment: I added another one also in my example. That's why I told you to make sure the variable is not an object but a string. `object.toString()`. It needs to be the value. Your calling an object value that is a function.

Comment: Like this?

 `var bu = <Link to={`../Members/{assignee}`} />;
bullet.url = bu.toString();'  This goes to `https://localhost:44382/[object%20Object]`

Comment: No, you convert  var bu = `members.id.toString()` first, then `<Link to={bu}>` you are converting the variable to a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190958/discussion-between-tallman-and-raymond).

Answer (score 0):

```
bullet.url = `'../Members/${member.name}'`;
```

add this way in object from to url

Comment: Thanks, but that navigates to `https://localhost:44382/'../Members/[member name]'` including the single quotes and the state is gone

Comment: Try ` <a href={ `#/..Members/${members.name}` }>{members.name}</a> `